# Reading file from android Internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin, bufferedreader, filenotfoundexception

I have placed a file in `my Tablet\Tablet\Android\data\my.app.package\files\data` called `test.txt` with a few lines of text. This is reported by Windows.

Kotlin is throwing an Exception (FileNotFound) and I have also tried specifying what I believe is the real path of the file, but cannot seem to get it using the following path:

`"/0/Android/data/my.app.package/files/data/test.txt"` (my app's data directory). This directory definitely exists as I can see it in device file managr.

This file contains 2 lines of text, which I am trying to read in to run specific tasks based on their values. I've tried with a BufferedReader, but I'm getting FileNotFound Exception...

This is my code:

```
fun readFile() {
    val yourFilePath = "/0/Android/data/my.app.package/files/data/test.txt"
    val yourFile = File(yourFilePath)

    print(yourFile.name)
    val file = File(yourFilePath)
    file.bufferedReader().forEachLine {
        println("value = $it")
    }

}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: `This directory definitely exists `. No it does not exist. `/storage/emulated/0/Android/...` exists. Have a look at getExternalFilesDir(null) for that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `filesDir` for pointing to the internal storage files directory
2. `use` blocks are good when you want to close stream automatically.
3. `try-catch` block to handle any IO exceptions, e.g. FileNotFoundException.

```
try {
    val file = File(filesDir, "test.txt")
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.bufferedReader().useLines {
            ...
        }
    }
} catch (e: IOException) {
    ...
}
```

Great article for a more in-depth look: [Medium](https://medium.com/@ramtintoosi/android-storage-i-o-with-kotlin-6fbef9489eb7)

Make sure your file exists by looking at your internal storage by:

`AndroidStudio -> View -> Tools Windows -> Android Device Explorer`

Comment: When you say "internal storage files directory," you mean "/0/Android/data/my.app.package/files/data"? Just trying to  understand better. Thanks!

Comment: @LorenzoBattilocchi Yes that's what I was referring to. Android has `filesDir` and `cacheDir` for accessing internal storage. If you have any questions let me know ;)

Comment: Awesome, I only learned about  the "Device Explorer" functionality today! Thanks a mil!

Comment: @LorenzoBattilocchi Your welcome, you can read that article it's really great ;)

Comment: Thank you! It's great having people like you always ready to share their wealth of knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

```
context.openFileInput(fileName).use { stream ->
   stream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
}
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the accepted answer?

Comment: @JeremyCaney the use of a lambda can make the code more readable and understandable, although the accepted answer shows error handling. I'm not sure if this does the same, as I have personally never experimented with lambdas before .